# How to keep selected tab as active after button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code

In Update Tab when I select an email id - after return view it set again add tab as active (coz it was set as active by default).

How to set the update tab as active after selecting email id - any idea .

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role ='presentation' class="active"><a href="#Add" data-toggle="tab">Add</a></li>
    <li role ='presentation'><a href="#Update" data-toggle="tab">Update</a></li>
    <li role ='presentation'><a href="#Delete" data-toggle="tab">Delete</a></li>
    <li role ='presentation'><a href="#menu3" data-toggle="tab">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="Add" class="tab-pane active">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Admin"))
{
    <div class="container container-fluid">
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.user_name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "User Name", @required = "true" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-address-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.full_name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Full Name", @required = "true" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-inbox" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.user_email, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email id", @required = "true" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.password, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password", @required = "true" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="fa fa-universal-access fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.role, ViewBag.role as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    &nbsp; Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
    </div>

    <div id="Update" class="tab-pane">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Load_data", "Admin")) { 
        <div class="container container-fluid">
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-5">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.user_email, ViewBag.user_email as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control",@onchange= "this.form.submit();" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        }

        <div id="Details">
            //Details of selected email id will be shown here 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Delete" class="tab-pane">

    </div>

    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share your Jquery code

Comment: There is no jquery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't do that, because your page is refreshing. If you want that then you need to do it **asynchronously**. I mean you need to use `@Ajax.BeginForm` or `jquery/ajax`.
If you don't want to do it `asynchronously`, then there is a work around way.

So while calling to your `action method` after selecting an email from your Update tab, assign a value in a **ViewBag**.

For example, in your action method,

```
{
 //Rest code
 ViewBag.TabValue = "Update";
 //Rest code
}
```

Now you can keep this value in a hidden field. For example, in your view,

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.TabValue" id="myTab"/>
```

So now, in your script, you can check this value and set your tab, like,

```
<script>
 if($('#myTab').val() == "Update")
 {
  $("#Update").focus(); //You can add a class as active so on...
 }
</script>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank , yes it works well , amazing . Can you refer me some good material on @Ajax.BeginForm ?

Comment: So happy that it worked for you. You can read [this blog.](http://www.nestedclasses.com/Blog/MVC/1) So easy and step by step how `@Ajax.BeginForm` works. Cheers.

Comment: Note that [AjaxHelper has been dropped from MVC6](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2015).